# PyCharm Asks "Is this intentional?" When Passing the Proper Arguments to Constructor of Generic Class

Tags: python, generics, constructor, pycharm, type-hinting

In the following case, *PyCharm 2020.2.3 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-202.7660.27* complains about me passing an `int` to the constructor of the class (it underlines the `2`):

> Passing int instead of [...].GenClass. Is this intentional?

```python
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


A = TypeVar("A")


class GenClass(Generic[A]):
    def __init__(self, p: int):
        self.p = p


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = GenClass[str](2)
```

I'm using Python 3.9. The fact that it expects a `GenClass` object seems to me like PyCharm wants the `self` object from the constructor. That looks like an error but maybe I'm using generics the wrong way.

**Could you please give me advice on whether the error is with me or with PyCharm? Thanks a lot!**